# How do I chain animation on a div with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a div element with a fixed height, which contains other elements.  The user can scroll through the div. I wish the user to be able to click buttons and go to a specific element within the scrollable div.  My code so far resets the postion of the scroll bar back to 0 if not at the top.  However, when in this state the animation to move to the element from the button click does not trigger.  If already at the top the animation will go to the desired location

My code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#scrollTo', function() {
  scrollToElement('#goto377', 1000);
});

function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
  if($('#scolly-div').scrollTop() != 0) {
    $('#scrolly-div').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1);
  }

  time = typeof(time) != 'undefined' ? time : 1000;
  verticalOffset = typeof(verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
  element = $(selector);
  offset = element.offset();
  offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset;
  $('#scrolly-div').animate({ scrollTop: offsetTop}, time);
}
```

How can I get both animations to work?

Comment: Try changing $('#scrolly-div').animate({ scrollTop: offsetTop}, time);
to $('#scrolly-div').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 1).animate({ scrollTop: offsetTop}, time);

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work. It just does the first animation

Comment: what if $('#scolly-div').scrollTop() == 0, does it do the other one, or does nothing. Also when you debug it, does it give you expected locals for "offsetTop"